# samba smbpasswd NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED gid_to_sid: winbind failed to find a sid for gid 100

Tags: samba

I am running SLES 11.4, having problems when users try to use `smbpasswd`.
As root if I do `smbpasswd` for a user account then that works.
Once the `smbpasswd` is set, samba server works fine and users can access or not access everything they should.
In turning on logging to level 10 writing specifically to `/var/log/samba.log`, I have found this:

```
gid_to_sid: winbind failed to find a sid for gid 100
LEGACY: gid 100 -> sid S-1-22-2-100

Forcing Primary Group to 'Domain Users' for ron
```

This log file is generated for doing the following at the command prompt, with myself logged in as a regular user in linux.  It ends with what looks like success, but the smbpasswd is not changed.

```
ron/Desktop> smbpasswd
Old SMB password:
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:

cli_negprot: SMB signing is mandatory and the server doesn't support it.
machine 127.0.0.1 rejected the negotiate protocol. Error was : NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED.
Password changed for user ron

ron/Desktop>
```

anyone know what the problem is and how to correct it?
I am trying to run samba server as simple as possible, with one folder shared and all samba passwords done locally.

Comment: `machine 127.0.0.1 rejected the password change: Error was : Password restriction`

Comment: think i got it, answer to follow after lunch

Answer (score 1):

so it seems if you are testing, as a non-root user when using smbpasswd you must use a password length 5 characters or greater.  When i used 4 it failed, but 5 or more worked.  As root you can `smbpasswd <username>` any character length successfully.  so be mindful of that.

my /etc/samba/smb.conf file is this and it fixed the problem,
specifically `server signing = auto`
The `obey pam restrictions` seem to have no affect,
I verified by changing all my password requirements {see pic below} numerous times and restarting smb and nmb and it seems that what makes it all work is `server signing = auto`

[image]

```
[global]
        workgroup = abc.com
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        map to guest = Bad User
        usershare allow guests = No
        add machine script = /usr/sbin/useradd  -c Machine -d /var/lib/nobody -s /bin/false %m$
        domain master = No
        security = user
        wins support = No
        log file = /var/log/samba.log
        log level = 10
#       client signing = auto
        server signing = auto      {need this to allow users to use smbpasswd successfully}

#       obey pam restrictions = Yes
#       pam password change = Yes
```

Comment: fyi i can turn on complicated passwords and check new passwords in yast, but that is not necessarily PAM.  So that's why i think the "obey pam restrictions" in samba seems to have no affect, because i don't have that specific syntax of `password  requisite  pam_pwcheck.so cracklib minlen=14 remember=24 difok=4 maxrepeat=3 ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1` in  **/etc/pam.d/password**